# Ajax POST com jQuery e Node.js Express sempre retornando 404: Not Found

Tags: ajax, node.js, express.js, http-status

Criei a rota abaixo para aceitar requisições POST, porém chamadas via AJAX para esta rota estão sempre retornando o erro 404: Not Found.

```
/* Arquivo: integracoes.js */
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// Esta rota funciona e não dá erro: http://localhost:3001/integracoes/consultas
router.get('/consultas', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('consultas');
});

// 404: Not Found quando chamado pela requisição Ajax descrita mais à frente nessa pergunta.
router.post('/consulta/statuspedido', function(req, res) {
    var statusDoPedido = 10;

    res.send(JSON.stringify({statuspedido: statuspedido})); 
});

module.exports = router;
```

No app.js eu faço uso dessa definição de rotas da seguinte forma:

```
var integracoes = require('./routes/integracoes');
app.use('/integracoes', integracoes);
```

Na página HTML eu estou utilizando a seguinte chamada Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/consulta/statuspedido',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
        debugger;

        textAreaDeResposta.val(imprimaCamposDoObjeto(data));
    },
    error: function(){
        textAreaDeResposta.val('Ocorreu um erro ao tentar consultar o status do pedido.');
    }
});
```

No Browser a resposta que obtenho é a seguinte:

**http://localhost:3001/consulta/statuspedido 404 (Not Found)**

O site está configurado para rodar na porta 3001, e todas as demais rotas do site (GET) estão funcionando. A única que não funciona é essa que estou tentando acessar via AJAX.

Por que a URL não é encontrada?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O [`express.Router()`](http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html#express-router) tem de ser usado como middleware. No teu exemplo estás a defenir corretamente uma "route" mas não estás a chamá-la como middleware. Tens de o passar à `app` e com uma "route" também, a partir da qual a outra é relativa.

Então falta-te algo assim:

```
app.use('/', router);
// ou
app.use('/consulta', router); // e no router "router.post('/statuspedido', ..."
// ou ainda
app.use('/consulta/statuspedido', router); // e no router "router.post('/', ..."
```

O conceito de "route" trouxe algo novo ao `express`, o de caminhos relativos. Da mesma maneira que num browser podemos apontar uma imagem para somente `imagem.png` e não `pasta/subpasta/imagens/imagem.png`, o router é mais ou menos assim. Então quando usas

```
app.use('/integracoes', router);
```

o `router` não sabe que já estás dentro de uma subpasta, essa informação é-lhe irrelevante.

Assim outros caminhos que sejam defenidos dentro dele **acrescem** ao caminho inicial. Como nos 3 exemplos que tinha colocado inicialmente. Na prática para o teu código o ponto de partida é `/integracoes` então o que defenires no router será em cima disso.

O caminho final para o qual o ajax deve apontar é então

```
/integracoes/consulta/statuspedido
```