# Configuração de rotas em NodeJS utilizando o Express 4.8

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou utilizando a versão v0.10.37 do Node e a 4.8 do Express. Estou tentando configurar a rota para o index. E os seguintes erros aparecem

> Error: Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]

Ou:

> Error: Cannot find module './app/routes/home'

**app/controller/home.js**

```
module.exports = function() {
    var controller = {};
    index: function(req, res) {

        res.render('index', {nome: 'Express'});
    };

    return controller; 
};
```

**app/routes/home.js**

```
var controller = require('./app/controllers/home');
module.exports = function(app) {

    app.get('/index', controller.index);
    app.get('/', controller.index, function() {});  

};
```

**config/express.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var home = require('./app/routes/home');
module.exports = function() {
    var app = express();

    app.set('port', 3000);
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.set('views', './app/views');
    //middleware

    home(app);

    return app;
};
```

Comment: Alane, conseguiste resolver este problema? A resposta ajudou?

Answer (score 3):

Tens alguns erros no teu código.

O teu primeiro erro não me parece relacionado com o código que mostras na pergunta. `Route.get()` implica usar i router do express e não vejo isso no teu código.

Há duas maneiras comuns de gerir rotas de maneira modular em ficheiros diferentes. Uma delas é com routes, como [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91287/129), a outra é como estás a usar (com alguns erros que vou explicar em baixo).

#### app/controller/home.js

Neste ficheiro queres criar e exportar o objeto controler certo? e quando o módulo for chamado ele deve retornar um objeto com propriedade, uma das quais o `index` que tem de ser uma função com parâmetros `req`, `res` e opcional `next`.

Nesse caso a sintaxe desse ficheiro deve ser assim:

```
var controller = {
    index: function(req, res) {
        res.render('index', {nome: 'Express'});
    }
};
module.exports = controller;
```

#### problemas a encontrar ficheiros

No Node.js quando usas um `require('./pasta/subpasta/ficheiro.js');` ele parte sempre da diretoria atual. Assim `./` é para ficheiros na mesma diretoria, `../` desce uma pasta. Assim as tuas *path* estão erradas, creio que precisas de `require('../etc');` nos dois que tens pois primeiro têm de descer a pasta e depois subir.

Assim o código completo deve ser:

app/controller/home.js // <- com ou sem "s" ??

```
var controller = {
    index: function(req, res) {
        res.render('index', {nome: 'Express'});
    }
};
module.exports = controller;
```

app/routes/home.js

```
var controller = require('../controllers/home'); // <- com ou sem "s" ??
module.exports = function(app) {

    app.get('/index', controller.index);
    app.get('/', controller.index, function() {});

};
```

config/express.js

```
var express = require('express');
var home = require('../app/routes/home');
module.exports = function() {
    var app = express();

    app.set('port', 3000);
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.set('views', './app/views');
    //middleware

    home(app);

    return app;
};
```

Comment: Opa, Sérgio, obrigada. Tinha visto a questão do module.exports ontem. Mas agora, em relação aos caminhos, mesmo voltando os diretórios, permanece o erro. Apenas quando passo o caminho absoluto funciona. Tem alguma sugestão? e o uso de __dirname e __filename?

Comment: @AlanePontes reparaste no problema do caminho com a palavra "controler"? às vezes tens no singular noutras no plural. Continuas com erro ainda? que erro dá?