# Erro configuração de rotas no NodeJS com Express

Tags: node.js, express.js, rotas

Estou com um problema na hora de iniciar o NodeJS, semelhante a este outro post 
[neste link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91800/configura%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-rotas-em-nodejs-utilizando-o-express-4-8), mas não teve mais feedback de quem perguntou e a solução apresentada na resposta não me serviu também.

O exemplo é de um livro, da Casa do Código, e são exemplos simples com erros de diretório mas que fazem me quebrar a cabeça pois estou começando com Node e Express.

Todo o exemplo foi utilizado o mesmo nome das variáveis do livro.

Eis o erro:

```
Error: Cannot find module './app/routes/home.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:25)
at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (E:\projects\contatooh\config\express.js:2:12)
at Module._compile (module.js:398:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:405:10)
at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
```

**contatooh/config/express.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var home = require('./app/routes/home')
module.exports = function() {
    var app = express();

    app.set('port', 3000);
    app.use(express.static('./public'));
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.set('views','./app/views');

    home(app);

    return app;
};
```

**contatooh/app/routes/home.js**

```
var controller = require('./app/controllers/home');

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/', controler.index);
    app.get('/index', controler.index);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

**contatooh/app/controllers/home.js**

```
module.exports = function(){
    var controller = {};
    controller.index = function(req, res){

        res.render('index'), {nome: 'Express'});
    };
    return controller;
}
```

Oraganização dos diretórios:

```
contatooh
    app
        controllers
            home.js
        models
        routes
            home.js
        views
            index.ejs
    config
        express.js
    node_modules
        ...
    public

    server.js
    package.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando fazes `.` estás dizendo "nesta atual pasta". Por exemplo, fazendo `./app/controller/home`, o que está na verdade a tentar importar é um file que se chama `home` que está situado numa pasta (ou repositório) que se chama `controller` que é uma sub-pasta da pasta `app`, que por sua vez se encontra na pasta donde estás a tentar importar. Mas acho que não é exatamente isso que querias fazer.

Se te encontras por exemplo no file `contatooh/app/routes/home.js` e queres importar `app/controller/home` (suponho que a pasta `app` seja a mesma nos dois casos), o que tens que fazer é fazer um "import relativo":

```
var controller = require("../controller/home");
```

`..` significa a pasta mãe (ou anterior) da pasta onde atualmente encontras-te, neste caso essa pasta é `app`, porque te encontras em `routes`. Depois disso só tens que especificar o path partindo de `app`. Se queres ir duas pastas para atras, só tens que fazer `../..`, e similmente se queres ir 3 ou 4, etc.

Penso que seja esse o teu problema, mesmo não tendo a certeza absoluta, porque não estou percebendo exatamente qual é a estrutura da tua aplicação.

Comment: Vou tentar alterar o caminho das pastas, retorno depois se funcionar

Comment: Fiz um update do post e do código.
Alterei a linha do 'express.js' de: `var home = require('./app/routes/home')`
para `var home = require('../app/routes/home');` . E também a do 'routes/home.js' de: `var controller = require('./app/controllers/home');` para `var controller = require('../controllers/home');` e parou de dar o erro de diretório. Valeu.